# What is the Probability distribution of number of products passing among 3 products, if the probability of passing test is given as 0.8?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

suppose 3 units of a product are tested. the result of the test is given in terms of pass or fail. if the probability that a unit will pass inspection is 0.8,find the probability distribution of the number of units that pass inspection?​

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Use the binomial distribution with p = 0.8